# Odoo UI widget - how to get settings from database?

Tags: odoo, odoo-9, odoo-view

I'm writing an Odoo v9 widget, which renders a URL, based on concatenation of a setting in the database, and the actual form fields.

The setting in the database I figure should live in ir_config_parameter. I'm inserting a default value with my module.

What's the best way to get this value when rendering the widget? Doing an async ajax call using

new Model("ir.config_parameter")

seems a little heavy handed. Is there a better way to be doing this?

Thanks.

Widget code:

```
    var UrlWidget2 = form_common.FormWidget.extend({
        start: function() {
            this._super();
            this.field_manager.on("field_changed:ref", this, this.display_result);
            this.display_result();
        },
        display_result: function() {
            var ref = this.field_manager.get_field_value("ref");

            if (!ref) return;

            var baseUrl = 'https://example.com'; //this is the value I want to get from the setting in the database. 
            var url = baseUrl + '/foo/' + ref;    

            this.$el.html('<a href="' + url + '" target="portal">View Externally</a><br /><br/>');
        }
    });
```

Comment: Where you want show value of setting? I mean it will be field of form?

Comment: From within the widget -where I am writing javascript - I need to get and make use of the config setting.

Comment: Show your js widget. I did something similar. Maybe I can help.

Comment: Added widget code.

Comment: What model is used for form? Why you can't just add `compute` field for this?

Comment: No python code allowed on Odoo SAAS.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [RPC](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/9.0/reference/javascript.html#rpc) for this. This is example which work for me:

```
var Model = require('web.DataModel'); 

var UrlWidget2 = form_common.FormWidget.extend({
        // just example how to get parameter from backend
        display_result: function() {
            var parameter = new Model('ir.config_parameter');
            // get fields value, key
            parameter.query(['value', 'key'])
                // criteria of search - record with id = 1
                .filter([['id', '=', 1]])
                // only one record
                .limit(1)
                .all()
                .then(function (parameter) {
                    // here data from server
                    console.log(parameter);
            });
        // ...
        }
    });
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks, I may have to do that - but as I said in my question, doing an ajax call is precisely what I wish to avoid. All I'm trying to do is render a link (or perhaps a few). To go back to the server, and render these links asynchronously, is just going to be slow.  So I'm looking for a better general way of achieving all this.

Comment: Let me know if you find something better. One more thing... I checked sources of different apps. I haven't seen something like as config. Work with `ir_config_parameter` occurs through RPC.